Sphinx doesn't pick up functions under multiple function decorators if they've been imported from a module
I'm trying to get Sphinx to generate docstrings for functions that have multiple decorators on them. I've created a pretty simple test case for this problem. We have four files:
server/__init__.py
server/test.py
utils/__init__.py
utils/test_decorators.py
When all the decorators are within the same local folder (so when the structure is server/__init__.py,server/test.py and server/test_decorators.py) Sphinx has zero issue picking out the docstrings when a function is under two decorators. However, when those decorators are moved to a separate module in a different folder, even with absolute imports, suddenly Sphinx is incapable of finding the docstrings if they're more than one level deep.
Code below:
server/__init__.py is empty
server/test.py:
from utils.test_decorators import my_decorator_1, my_decorator_2
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@my_decorator_1
def test_func_1(num):
    '''
    This is a test docstring. This one should appear 
    '''
    print(num)
    return

@my_decorator_1
@my_decorator_2
def test_func_2():
    '''
    This is also a test docstring for chained decorators.
    '''
    return 0

@app.route('/test_1')
def test_rest():
    '''
    This is a test docstring for single-level decorators using Flask.
    '''
    return "Hello, Flask!"

@app.route('/test_2')
@my_decorator_1
def home():
    '''
    This is a test docstring for chained decorators using Flask.
    '''
    return "Hello, Flask!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

utils/__init__.py is empty
utils/test_decorators.py:
import functools
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator_1(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling the function")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("After calling the function")
        return result
    return wrapper

def my_decorator_2(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Starting execution")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Execution finished")
        return result
    return wrapper

